# how to insert default image into database with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

**UPDATED:**
I have a form which have image upload field which have not required field. Now i want to if anyone submitting form without uploading image then a default image will be inserted into database. How can i do that with PHP?

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route($base_route.'.eventEdit', ['event_id' => $event->event_code]) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="general_form" novalidate="novalidate">
     <input name="name" type="text" value="something" class="name">
     <input name="name" type="file" value="DefaultImageName"  class="image">
     <button class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This should be done on serverside

Comment: @JonasW. how can i achieve this in serverside? any idea?

Comment: I'd store `NULL` in the DB and populate the field with the default image when it is read back again. Taking your question at face value, check the sent form data in your Laravel controller and fill in the default image if it's blank.

Comment: I understand the scenario that if `isset` files is `null` then insert image but don't know the actual way to do. I have failed many times.

Comment: canyou show the controller where you are saving images to DB?

Answer (score 1):

you could put a defult value in the image column in your database, this way all users will get this image, unless you specify a different image, because it will override it...

this method worked for me...

Comment: Could you explain further how one would go about doing that? Do you have an actual code snippet that accomplishes what you've described?

Comment: I have 12 default image. If anyone submitted form without uploading any image then default image will be uploaded from these 12 image randomly.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you are not able to do this, you can just send data to the server and process it on serverside. Eg. Save to database.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a Javascript library, running in your web-browser. It does not have access to your database and should not have access to your database.

Your application server has access to your database and there you should default the image.

If your image is a field of a table where you insert anyway and you want to specify a default image when a record is inserted, then you need to alter your table and specify a default value for your images. In this case your problem can be solved solely by doing such an alter.

If your case is not as simple as above, then on your server where you insert the images you may check whether the image was posted and if not, then insert a default image.

Also, you duplicate the name of your tags, you might want to specify different values for the name attribute for your two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageName = "default.jpg";
if (isset($_POST["name_of_the_image_file"])) {
      //move functionality of the image file
      $imageName = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}

$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET name='Doe' and image_field='$imageName' WHERE id='$id'";
$conn->query($sql);
```